# text parsing in php

Tags: php

In my project I get back a name of a person through a php response. And I store that name in a variable.

So the name could be like James Smith or Sakhu Ali Khan or anything else.

I want to replace the spaces between the names with "."

Suppose I get the James Smith and I will save it in `$userName`

Now I want to parse `$userName` and then replace the spaces with "." so my

```
$parsedUserName == James.Smith
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in php. I am not very much familiar with text parsing.

Best
Zeeshan

Comment: How do you plan to handle more complicated names such as: Oscar de la Hoya?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) function to do this:

```
$parsedUserName = str_replace(' ', '.', $userName);
```

If you're using UTF-8 or another multibyte character set then you should use [`mb_str_replace()`](http://php.net/mb_str_replace) instead.

```
$parsedUserName = mb_str_replace(' ', '.', $userName);
```

Comment: +1 Good answer; it might be worth trimming before you do a replace so you don't end up with something like John.Smith.

Comment: what about two spaces?  John..Smith

Comment: There is no character whose UTF-8 encoded word contains the byte 0x20 other than U+0020.

Answer (score 0):

`$parsedUserName = str_replace(" ", ".", $userName);`

Make sure the sanatize the data you get first however. Use things like [trim()][1] and [filter_var()][2] to make sure the data is what you expect it to be.

So do something like this:

$userName = trim($userName);
$userName = filter_var($userName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$parsedUserName = str_replace(" ", ".", $userName);

Answer (score 0):

i would use regexp  (i can always find an excuse to use it) for catching multiple spaces

```
$parsedUserName = preg_replace('/ +/','.',trim($userName));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
$parsedUserName = str_replace(array("  ", " "), ".", $userName);
```

In case you have more than one whitespaces, so:

```
James        Smith
```

is replaced with:

```
James.Smith
```